# Nested function techniques for different "flow paths" in swift

Tags: swift, nested

I'm learning object oriented things and trying to incorporate nested functions into my code so I can gain understanding of how these different operations flow and work, specifically nested functions.
I want to pass values from one function to another then another and, depending on the calculations within each nested func, output certain final numbers. I'm having trouble understanding how to grab and re-declare return values inside a method so they can be used again.

Crude single nested example:

```
func increaseNumbers(numOne: Double, numTwo: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
var numOneIncreased = numOne + 2
var numTwoIncreased = numTwo + 5

    func playWithNumbersMore(warpOne: Double, warpTwo: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
    if warpOne < 50 {
    var adjustedOne = warpOne + 16.5
    var adjustedTwo = warpTwo + 20.8
    } else { do nothing... }
        return (adjustedOne, adjustedTwo)
    }

playWithNumbersMore(warpOne: numOneIncreased, warpTwo: numTwoIncreased)
// How do i re-assign the return values inside playWithNumbersMore?

return (something, somethingTwo)
}
```

Crudely speaking this is what I want to do if possible:

```
func increaseNumbers(numOne: Double, numTwo: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
var numOneIncreased = numOne + 2
var numTwoIncreased = numTwo + 5

    func playWithNumbersMore(warpOne: Double, warpTwo: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
    if warpOne < 50 {
    var adjustedOne = warpOne + 16.5
    var adjustedTwo = warpTwo + 20.8
    } else { do nothing... }
        return (adjustedOne, adjustedTwo)
    }

// I want to be able to take return values and do more with them... as well as redefine them 
// on completion of final "parent function"

// Sort of like this:
var newNumbToPlayOne = adjustedOne
var newNumbToPlayTwo = adjustedTwo

func playMoreWithNewNumbers...

}
```

Is this possible or am I off the rails?

Comment: Can you format your code properly? If you do, you'll realise your braces are not balanced.

Comment: Also, can you show some sample inputs and outputs? e.g. "When `numOne` is 1 and `numTwo` is 2, `increaseNumbers` should return..."

Comment: @Sweeper totally not the point of the post but I did make the code more on point.

Comment: @Sweeper i dont think i need to go that in-depth as Alexander Nikolaychuk answered my question

Answer (score 1):

```
func increaseNumbers(numOne: Double, numTwo: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
var numOneIncreased = numOne + 2
var numTwoIncreased = numTwo + 5

    func playWithNumbersMore(warpOne: Double, warpTwo: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
    if warpOne < 50 {
    var adjustedOne = warpOne + 16.5
    var adjustedTwo = warpTwo + 20.8
        return (adjustedOne, adjustedTwo)
    }

let result = playWithNumbersMore(warpOne: numOneIncreased, warpTwo: numTwoIncreased)
        numOneIncreased = result.0 // result.0 is a adjustedOne
        numTwoIncreased = result.1 // result.1 is a adjustedTwo

return result
}
```

This is how you can use the result of playWithNumbersMore data.
Am I wrong or it is what a are look for?

Comment: result.0 and result.1 you can assign to any new variable and do whatever you need in your parent function

Comment: @ Alexander Nikolaychuk Thats exactly what i was looking for. I realize I did see this in other places I looked up nested use but they are always such complex examples. Thanks dude!

Comment: Your answer has been +1 :)